# What is this component (is it a rectifier?)

Tags: power-electronics, identification, inverter, mains, repair

I'm currently reverse-engineering an air conditioner inverter circuit.

I have stumbled upon a weird package.

The thing is I can't de-solder this component, so I can't read the letters on it.

Do you know what this is?

Since it's connected to the capacitor, it might be a full-bridge rectifier, but I couldn't say for sure. A part number or a datasheet would be very helpful.

edit - hey guys, I think it's time to let it go. You can't possibly reverse engineer everything you see. I've learned it the hard way. But also I've learned so much more about power electronics along the way. I guess that what actually matters.
Search for "Intelligent Power Module" for to learn about this "inverters" and "High efficient BLDC motor Drivers" if you interested. I have lost so much time because I didn't know that particular Word. Thanks everyone.

[image: photo of PCB]

[image: photo of PCB]

Comment: yeah that seems plausable,

Comment: My guess is there is two motor drives - the fan and the compressor. So I’d say it is a mosfet/igbt triple phase driver module.

Comment: @Kartman yeah but that's on the Left (take a look at the 1st picture). as you can see in the last pic, it's the  3 Phase output(UVW) right above that IGBT package. even if, this one is also an IGBT package, then where is the rectifier?

Comment: Is this on the input line and neutral, or the output? You call it an inverter, so I would assume DC to AC conversion is going on somewhere in here.

Comment: @Hearth This is an Split air conditioner Inverter, it converts Single Phase AC in to DC and then convert into 3 Phase AC (aka BLDC motor driver). Single Phase ---> HVDC--->3 Phase

Comment: Okay, so is this device connected to the input AC or output AC?

Comment: @Hearth input single Phase AC (the L, N mentioned on the 2nd Pic) and Outputs 3 Phase AC ( the Three terminals right besides to L and N terminals)

Comment: I'm guessing it's a power electronics module being used as an active rectifier, then.

Comment: @Hearth Exactly my guess too. but I couldn't identify(Part Number/datasheet) of that module

Comment: @JohnCortex The part number, if it's not printed on one of the sides of the module, will be printed on the side that's facing down towards the PCB. You don't normally print on thermal surfaces; CPUs are the exception there.

Comment: @Hearth no can do since I have to de-solder the components but I have to return the board to It's original owner. I think this is a failed expedition and it's time to let it go. Thanks for the suggestions tho.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an IGBT (or similar) three phase bridge module. Usually something like 6 IGBT thermally bonded to efficiently drive a 3-phase motor. Often they have nice features like thermal sensors and integrated gate drive (optimized for the transistors). Search for 3-phase IGBT pack or something like that, Semikron does some nice ones for example (but many other too, look at Infineon, On Semi, etc)

Comment: already did that but no luck on that. the thing is, If that's an IGBT package, where is the Rectifier?  this circuit has big'ol electrolytic caps, and the power source for this Board is single phase AC.so this board diffo need a AC to DC conversion